# How to access pages based on product ids

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am having a problem in navigating from one page to another.

```
<?php
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                 <div class="list">
                <p><a href="Commodities.php?v=<?php echo $row['idproducts'] ?>"><?php echo $row['productname']?></a></p>
                <div class="images">
                       <img src="<?php echo  'images/'. $row['image']  ?>" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
                    </div>
                }
            <div class="text">
              <p>
                   <?php echo $row['description'] ?>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
<?php
```

Here the problem is that when I click on the product link it does not take to the desired product description page. Rather than it is redirected to the same commodities page. So i am not understanding what to do.So please help me to find out my error..

Comment: when i give Commodities.php?v=1 then it redirects me to the same page rather than redirecting me to the desired product with id 1

Comment: any framework are you using??

Comment: And what's the products page name?

Comment: in which url you want to redirect it?

Comment: the products are dynamiccaly fetched from the database

Comment: the prduct names are cocoabean.php,cashewnut.php etc

Comment: @MaheshGulve Use Full URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed php tag inside your markup. please have a look updated code

```
 <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <div class="list">
        <p><a href="Commodities.php?v=<?php echo $row['idproducts']; ?>"><?php echo $row['productname']; ?></a></p>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="<?php echo 'images/' . $row['image']; ?>" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
        </div>
          <!-- remove this end curly braces from ur markup-->
        <div class="text">
         <p>
                <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<!-- close while loop in proper place. as of now $row['description'] outside from while loop -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in your php statements..

Echo statements are not terminated with (;)

```
<?php
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
             <div class="list">


        <p><a href="Commodities.php?v=<?php echo $row['idproducts']; ?>"><?php echo $row['productname']; ?></a></p>


         <div class="images">

                <img src="<?php echo  'images/'. $row['image']; ?>" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />

            </div>

        <div class="text">

             <p>

            <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
        </p>
        </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>   
  <?php }?>
 <?php
```